# Which of these forms of passing a lambda to jQuery's document.ready event is the correct one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object called `foo` like so in which I have encapsulated by event handler for document.ready event of jQuery.

```
var foo = new function()
{
  var OnDocumentReady = function() { ... }
}
```

However, upon trying any of these forms, my event handler is not called.

```
$(document).ready(foo.OnDocumentReady);

$(document).ready(foo().OnDocumentReady);

$(document).ready(foo()["OnDocumentReady"]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you have locally scoped `OnDocumentReady` to the variable environment inside of `foo`. You need to actually attach it as a property of `foo`. You can do that with `this`.

```
var foo = new function()
{
  this.OnDocumentReady = function() { ... }
}
```

And now your first approach will work:

```
$(document).ready(foo.OnDocumentReady);
```

The other two will not work because using `new function()` is going to construct an object, which is not a function. Calling an object as a function will cause an exception.